# Wordpress widget new instance creates content duplicates

Tags: widgets, mysql, sidebar, post-meta, register-sidebar

I have a custom made widget that I wrote and I want to display two instances of the same widget in the same widget area. When I drag and drop new widget instance to the widget area inside admin panel and put some new data inside custom fields and save, when I go back to the home page I see both new and old widget with the same content. I think it might be `update` function problem, but I wrote it following wordpress docs so it looks the same. Here is the code:

functions.php

```
/**
 * Register new custom wiget
*/

class Sole_Source_Main_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_options = array(
            'classname' => 'sole_source_main_widget',
            'description' => 'Main content widget'
        );
        parent::__construct('sole_source_main_widget', 'Sole Source Widget', $widget_options);
    }

    //back-end display

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
     $instance = $old_instance;
     $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
     $instance['description'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['description'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['description'] ) : '';
     $instance['image'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['image'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['image'] ) : '';

     return $instance;
}

public function form( $instance ) {
$title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : ''; ?>
<?php $description = ! empty( $instance['description'] ) ? $instance['description'] : ''; ?>
<?php $image = ! empty( $instance['image'] ) ? $instance['image'] : ''; ?>
<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />

    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'description' ); ?>">Description:</label>
    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'description' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'description' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $description ); ?>" />

    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>">Image URL:</label>
    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'image' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $image ); ?>" />
</p><?php
}

    //front-end display
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

  $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance[ 'title' ] );
    $description = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['description']);
    $image = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['image']);
    ?>

    <?php echo $args['before_widget'] . $args['before_title']; ?> <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"></img> <?php $args['after_title']; ?>
  <?php echo $args['before_widget'] . $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title']; ?>
    <?php echo $args['before_widget'] . $args['before_title'] . $description . $args['after_title']; ?>

  <?php echo $args['after_widget'];
    }
}

add_action('widgets_init', function() {
    register_widget('Sole_Source_Main_Widget');
});
```

sidebar.php

```
<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" role="complementary">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'main-widget' ); ?>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'main-widget' ); ?>
    </div>
</aside><!-- #secondary -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the widget class. The problem you have is that you are displaying the widget area, that contains the widgets, twice in your `sidebar.php`:

```
<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" role="complementary">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'main-widget' ); // this will display all the widgets in your main-widget sidebar ?>
</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'main-widget' ); // this will display again all the widgets in your main-widget sidebar ?>
    </div>
</aside><!-- #secondary -->
```

The second widget in each sidebar display is probably hidden due to some CSS, but I bet it is there, twice, once on the left and one on the right.

So, do not call `dynamic_sidebar( 'main-widget' );` twice.

From what I understand you want to wrap the widgets in certain divs so you can put them on two columns. For this you need to filter the `before-widget` and `after-widget` params of each widget via the `dynamic_sidebar_params` filter. Or, better yet you could use some CSS to do the trick.

Here is a starter PHP code that will add wrappers to each widget in your target widget area:

```
/**
 * @param array $params
 */
function sole_add_widget_columns_wrapper( $params ) {
    // Add the opening wrapper tag
    $params[0]['before_widget'] = PHP_EOL . '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">' . PHP_EOL . $params[0]['before_widget'];

    // Add the closing wrapper tag
    $params[0]['after_widget'] = $params[0]['after_widget'] . PHP_EOL . '</div><!-- close wrapper -->' . PHP_EOL;
}

/**
 * @param string $index
 */
function sole_handle_main_widget_area_columns( $index ) {
    // We only want to deal with the main widget area
    if ( 'main-widget' !== $index ) {
        return;
    }

    // Filter each widget params and add the wrappers
    add_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', 'sole_add_widget_columns_wrapper', 10, 1 );

    // Hook an action to remove the filter above after we are done with this widget area.
    // This way we don't affect other widget area that may come, on the same page, after this one.
    add_action( 'dynamic_sidebar_after', 'sole_remove_main_widget_area_columns_filter', 10 );
}
add_action( 'dynamic_sidebar_before', 'sole_handle_main_widget_area_columns', 10 );

function sole_remove_main_widget_area_columns_filter() {
    remove_filter( 'dynamic_sidebar_params', 'sole_add_widget_columns_wrapper', 10 );
}
```

This code will wrap each widget, it will not put even and odd widgets into two column wrappers.

Comment: I removed second sidebar call and changed column width to 12 columns. Now it gets displayed full width of the screen in red background. I added a second widget and it works fine but the second widget content gets displayed right under the first widget, not on the right side as I wanted it. Yes that's what I want, left side to be red widget and right side white widget with only some text. Can you explain a little bit more on how to use those filter exactly? I'm not familiar with filters at all. I need to apply it for sidebar register or widget class?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the PHP code. I hope it helps, although I believe a CSS solution is more appropriate for your situation.